# PhoneGap and Twilio Browser-phone

Tags: cordova, twilio

I'm building a phonegap project (for iOS/Android), that will include a page allowing phone numbers to be dialled through Twilio. I've chosen the Browserphone option to achieve this, and it all works fine when testing on Chrome desktop, but hangs and does nothing when run as an app on either an android or ios device.

The reason for this is almost certainly that the browser needs user permission to access the device microphone, so does anyone know how to set the webview part of the Cordova system to automatically allow  the microphone to be accessed? I've tried the obvious stuff, like setting media permissions etc, but it made no difference.

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: did you ever get twilio working?

Comment: I got it working via a different method that required me to build a routeing switch on the server side, and to connect call routes via PSTN and the Twilio REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Twilio Client JavaScript library on most mobile browsers, or web view applications (they don't support WebRTC or Flash). You can, however, use the [Twilio Client Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap).